# How does assigning KeySetView to MultableSet works in Kotlin when they are of different implementation hirarchy

Tags: kotlin

Consider the following line

```
   private val variable: MutableSet<String> = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()
```

`MutableSet` implements `Set, MutableCollection`and `KeySetView` implemets `Set, Collection` how is it possible to assign the object `KeySetView` to `MutableSet` because they are not of compatible types.

What am I missing in Kotlin assignments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't have read-only collection types, so a Set coming from Java is equivalent to a MutableSet in Kotlin. The compiler hints describe it as mapped to the type `(Mutable)Set`. The word *Mutable* is in parentheses to indicate that it's possible that the Java code you're working with might not have intended for it to be used in a mutable way and that you should check the javadocs for the method to see if it says something like "do not modify the returned Set", and if so, you should treat it as a read-only Kotlin `Set`.

ConcurrentHashMap doesn't have a Kotlin standard-library counterpart, so `newKeySet` is a Java method and returns a Java Set, which is a Kotlin (Mutable)Set.